# Vlookup equilivant in presto sql

Tags: sql, presto

Is there a way of doing something like a vlookup in presto?

I am given a bunch of IDs in one table that looks like this.[image]

I have another table that gives me back the lookup values. so 503203 would have a particular name, a price, and a category.

How can I add three columns after each named product to show me the corresponding values? some thing like this?[image]

Comment: Do the four product columns appear in the output as just a single column?

Comment: the product column are outputted as separate columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `left join`:

```
select t1.*,
       t21.*, t22.*, t23.*, t24.*
from table1 t1 left join
     table1 t21
     on t1.product1 = t21.productid left join
     table1 t22
     on t1.product2 = t22.productid left join
     table1 t23
     on t1.product1 = t23.productid left join
     table1 t24
     on t1.product1 = t24.productid ;
```